# Find last child element in the parent element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I find last element inside a parent element? In case they change dynamically.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `:last` ? What have you tried ?

Comment: yes but this just find the last sibling of parent not child.

Comment: Then write it : `$(this).siblings().last()`

Comment: Please explain the problem you're trying to solve, and add context to that problem. What is it in response to, what are you planning to do with the element that you find?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('.parent').children().last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:last` jQuery selector:

```
  $('.parent > :last')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:last-child` selector.

Like this `$(".parent :last-child").css('border', '2px solid red');`

Comment: `.parent > :last-child` may be faster.